# NLog webservice target how do I specify json layout in appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, nlog

I can't seem to find an example. I want to Use NLog as a webservice, but when I add it I am seeing HTTP POST with a body of {}. How in appsettings.json do I specify the json layout?

```
   "NLog": {
      "targets": {
        "allfile":{
          "type":"File",
          "fileName":"/tmp/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log",
          "layout":"${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
        },
        "dabomb": {
          "type": "webservice",
          "url": "http://localhost:9990/api/foo/",
          "protocol": "JsonPost",
         ????? WHAT GOES HERE ??????
        }
      },
      "rules": [
        {
          "logger": "*",
          "minLevel": "Debug",
          "writeTo": "dabomb"
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```json
"dabomb": {
   "type": "webservice",
   "url": "http://localhost:9990/api/foo/",
   "protocol": "JsonPost",
   "parameters": [
   { 
      "Name": "",
      "Layout": {
         "type": "JsonLayout", 
         "Attributes": [
         {
            "name": "level",
            "layout": "${level}"
         },
         {
            "name": "message",
            "layout": "${message}"
         } ]
      }
   } ]
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target